# In history of algebra, who was the first to add one equation to another equation?

Tags: mathematics, algebra

In history of algebra, who was the first to add one equation to another equation? Someone gave me the name of an Italian mathematician of Renaissance period, but I lost the email. I wish to make it a bit more precise: adding two equations (hence involving unknowns), not just equalities: the latter was apparently dealt with by Euclid.

Comment: Do you mean taking linear combinations of simultaneous equations?

Comment: Yes, in modern terms it is a linear combination of simultaneous equation. In old times it was likely to be adding one of two simultaneous equation to, or subtracting from, another one with the simpler to get a simpler equtions.

Comment: Is the question about *any* use of $f = 0 = g \Rightarrow af+bg = 0$ for polynomials $f,g,$ or only the special case where it is used to eliminate a variable?

Answer (score 6):

For sure, the technique was used by Leonhard Euler (15 April 1707 – 18 September 1783).

See : [Elements of Algebra (English transl., 1822)](https://books.google.it/books?id=Xf5eAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA208), page 208:

> Since the two equations are,
>
> > $x+y=a$, and
> >
> > $x-y=b$;
>
> if we add the one to the other, we have $2x=a+b$.

The first German edition of the [Elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elements_of_Algebra) was in 1770.

---

An earlier example seems to be in Gerolamo Cardano (24 September 1501 – 21 September 1576)'s [Ars Magna (1545)](https://books.google.it/books?id=ZMZY79bvOPgC&pg=PA74), but we have to consider that we are reading a modern English translation: the original Latin text can be quite different (see [Caput IX (page 21)](http://www.filosofia.unimi.it/cardano/testi/operaomnia/vol_4_s_4.pdf)).

Comment: The second link is returning 404.