# Did Romans know formulae?

Tags: roman-empire

I read a previous question on Roman engineers and I was surprized that nobody referred to the Pantheon: its dome is an unrivalled wonder of architecture. Roads and aqueducts can be built without theoritical notions.

It is amazing that people with such a crippled numeral system and little or no math could build such a temple, in comparison to which pyramids and parthenon are child's play.

Do you know if there is any record of formulae the architects used to calculate the shape and the load-carryng capacity of materials and structures?

Comment: They did not have formulae, the earliest versions appear in Diophantus's Arithmetica c. 250 AD, but that does not mean that they did not have a developed mathematical and theoretical background. It was based on Euclidean geometry, see [Hadrianic Architecture and Geometry](https://www.jstor.org/stable/505986). We also have a multi-volume theoretical treatise [*De architectura*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_architectura) (c. 20 BC) written by famous Roman architect Vitruvius, although it was written before cross vaulting and domes were introduced. Modern way is not the only way.

Comment: Not in modern sense... Have you have seen an "algebraic expression" of Cardano ? See [this post](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/7465/in-history-of-algebra-who-was-the-first-to-add-one-equation-to-another-equation) with the original text linked.